# math.log() results in "ValueError: math domain error"

Tags: math, python-2.x, frequency, midi

This is a frequency to MIDI note converter, but I can't seem to get the math to work properly. Specifically, with the `math.log()` function. This will produce an output of 69.0 most of the time, but it usually outputs "ValueError: math domain error", if I input any number below 440. How should I fix it?

```
    #d=69+12*log(2)*(f/440)
    #f=2^((d-69)/12)*440
    #d is midi, f is frequency

    import math
    f=raw_input("Type the frequency to be converted to midi: ")
    d=69+(12*math.log(int(f)/440))/(math.log(2))
    print d`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Python 2 uses integer division. Anything below 440 will evaluate to 0 which is then passed to `math.log()`.

```
>>> 500/440
1
>>> 440/440
1
>>> 439/440
0
>>> math.log(0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: math domain error
```

The easiest way is to enable Python 3 style so called true division by placing this line at the top of your file:

```
from __future__ import division
```

Now Python 2 will behave as you might have expected:

```
>>> 439/440
0.9977272727272727
>>> math.log(439/440)
>>> math.log(439/440)
-0.0022753138371355394
```

As alternatives, you can convert the dividend and/or divisor to a float:

```
d=69+(12*math.log(int(f)/440.0))/(math.log(2))
```

or

```
d=69+(12*math.log(float(f)/440))/(math.log(2))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining that! It now works :D

Answer (score 0):

If Python 2, it looks like an integer division makes the product in parenthesis inexact. Try to divide by 440.0 instead.